# Что такое "пуща"

Tags: этимология

"Пуща" в значении "лес" употребляется почему-то только по отношению к Беловежской Пуще. Почему так? А также, есть русское слово "пуще" в значении "больше". Это однокоренные слова или просто созвучные?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово ПУЩА имеет древнее славянское происхождение. Оно образовалось в праславянский период от краткого прилагательного *pustъ > пустъ «пуст», первонач. «дикий, незаселенный» с помощью суффикса -j-a: сущ.* pustja > пуща «обширный, густой, труднопроходимый лес» (сочетание stj изменилось в щ). От этого же корня *pustъ происходят* пустой, пустыня, пускать (пущать), пусть*.

Слово ПУЩЕ  "больше" является сравн. степенью прилагательного *пустъ* (пустой), о котором уже сказано выще. Следовательно, этимологически ПУЩА и ПУЩЕ являются родственниками.

Кстати, слово **пуща** употребляется не только по отнощению к Беловежскому заповеднику. В Белоруссии есть еще Налибокская пуща. В современном языке пуща не просто 'лес', а 'лес реликтовый, дикий', т.е. в самом первом значении. Беловежской пуще как охраняемому природному объекту, кстати, уже 600 лет исполнилось.